# How to replace numbers with NAs with condition

Tags: r, matrix, replace, na

I have two matrices, X1 and X2, with the same dimensions.

X2 has NAs values.

How can I put NAs values in X1 in the same position of X2 (replacing the values in X1)?

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `replace`

```
replace(X1, is.na(X2), NA)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   NA    4    7
#[2,]    2    5    8
#[3,]    3   NA    9
```

Or

```
X1 * NA^is.na(X2)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   NA    4    7
#[2,]    2    5    8
#[3,]    3   NA    9
```

Or as @Roland mentioned in the comments

```
is.na(X1) <- is.na(X2)
```

BTW,

```
X1 + X2 - X2
#Error in X1 + X2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Bottomline is that both the solutions I posted is general and works for non-numeric matrices as well.

#### data

```
X1 <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
X2 <- matrix(c(NA, "a", "b", "c",  "a", NA, "c","f", "a"), 3, 3)
```

Comment: Or `is.na(X1) <- is.na(X2)` because it looks nice.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
X1[is.na(X2)] <- NA
```

In case if the data is completely numeric,try

`NA` + any number is `NA`. You can add `X2` and then subtract it.

```
X1 + X2 - X2
```

Comment: First of all that is not my data and secondly, it won't work always.  See my edit.